# CSS Image Viewer - Align centre of the screen

Tags: css, image, popup, center, viewer

I want to use the below image enlarger/viewer but i would like the popup of the enlarged image to appear on the center of the screen.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css_smart_image_enlarger/

I tried many ways but was unsuccessful....

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To solve these issues I usually query the DOM with JavaScript to find out the size of the window. I then use:

```
document.getElementById('popup').style.top = window_height - popup_height / 2;
document.getElementById('popup').style.left = window_width - popup_width / 2;
```

The positioning of the popup must be set to 'absolute' in the CSS. To get height (same for width) I use:

```
if (document.body.clientHeight) {
    window_height = document.body.clientHeight;
} else {
    window_height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

If your div doesn't have an id you can still pass the object reference to the JavaScript function like:

```
<div class='popup' onmouseover='javascript:openPopup(this);'> ... </div>
```

And, in a nearby piece of code:

```
function openPopup(element) {

    // Get window's height and width using the code above

    element.style.top  = window_height - popup_height / 2;
    element.style.left = window_width - popup_width / 2;

}
```

That is, instead of querying the DOM to get the object by the ID, you directly pass the object to the JavaScript function.

Comment: thanks! but the code has a div class... could you kindly give me an example from the code pleasE? much appreciated

Comment: Just put the ID on the span like this: <span id="popup"></span>

Comment: really appreciate your support...but i may be being dumb - i tried all the above but no luck..I got __________________________________ 

function openPopup(element) { 
 
    // Get window's height and width using the code above 
    
    if (document.body.clientHeight) { 
    window_height = document.body.clientHeight; 
    window_width = document.body.clientWidth; 
} else { 
    window_height = window.innerHeight; 
    window_height = window.innerWidth; 
}
 
    element.style.top  = window_height - 200 / 2; 
    element.style.left = window_width - 200 / 2; 
 
}

Comment: this is for the div________________________
  <div class="ienlarger" onmouseover='javascript:openPopup(this);'><a href="#nogo"><img src="images/1646.jpg" alt="thumb" class="resize_thumb" /><span>
  
    <img src="images/234026.jpg" alt="large" /></span></a></div> 


_____________ and for the CSS i have   .ienlarger a:hover span { 
 display:block;
 position: absolute;
_____________________________________________________ We're nearly there please could you test it with the code i am using with - http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css_smart_image_enlarger/   THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Try to strip off the a:hover part.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this if you got a fixed with..

.popup {
position: absolute;
width: 140px;
margin-left: -70px; 
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
}

Comment: nope that doesn't work at all...there should be css properties in the .ienlarger a:hover span _______tried mostly all the properties but no luck

Comment: This works when i try it:

.ienlarger a span {
background-color:#000000;
color:#FFCC00;
display:none;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;
left:50%;
margin-left:-70px;
padding:10px 10px 13px;
position:absolute;
text-decoration:none;
width:150px;
}

But this is not vertical... i guess it would be clever to use some javascript